# How does RSA blind signature calculation works?

Tags: rsa, blind-signature

I am having a struggle calculating (ii) and (iii), Can anybody help me with the calculation?

RSA blind signature algorithm:
Given two prime numbers: $p=11$ and $q=3$
The message to be signed is: $M=6$
The public key is: $e=7$

- (i) List all the possible candidates of the blinding factor $R$.
  $n=33$
  $\phi(33)=20$
  $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,10,13,14,16,17,19,20,23,25,26,28,29,31,32\}$
- (ii) If the chosen $R$ is $2$, find out $R^{−1}$(inverse).
- (iii) Calculate the signature with blinding factor $S’$.

Comment: Hint for (ii): RSA blind signature operates modulo $N$, and the desired inverse is modulo $N$. Research what [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) means, and how it is computed. Hint for (iii): there's nothing beyond applying the formulas defining [RSA blind signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature).

Comment: So in this case, inverse R is 17 and S' is 16?

Comment: I confirm for $R$, not for $S'$. Either your equations are not those I linked to, or one of us made a mistake. Suggestion: check your $d$ by signing $M$ yielding $S$ without blinding, and verifying that against $M$. And from your $S'$ try to compute $S=S'\,R^{-1}\bmod n$, and see if that's the same $S$ as above.